# Chart View Android Custom View

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, canvas, android-custom-view

I gone through some Android libraries but can't get something. How can we make such a view like this graph?

[image: 1]

any help to this will be a lot for me
could u refer some reference code or some sort of library though which I could achieve this

Comment: Consider MPAndroidChart: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: thankyou i'll look into it